# Map and join an array in a Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an array in Ruby:

`arr = ["aba", "bab", "abb"]`

I want to replace all of the "a" with "c", then join the elements together with a semi-colon.

```
# Replace "a" with "c"
replaced_arr = arr.map {|element| element.sub("a", "c") }

# Join with a ";"
joined_string = replaced_arr.join(";")

# "cbc; bcb; cbb"
```

**How can I do this in a Rails view**?

Doing 
`<%= arr.map(|element| element.sub("a", "c")).join(";") %>` gives me the error `syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76722105/retrieve-unique-email-addresses-from-users-based-on-multiple-domains-without-usi can anyone please help me to answer this query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternative (and shorter) way to do this

```
<%= arr.join(";").gsub("a","c") %>
```

Also the error you are facing is because of wrong syntax. `map` accepts a block, so it should start with `{}` i.e.

```
arr.map{|element| element.sub("a", "c")}.join(";")
```

Also to note using `sub` will only replace the first occurrence of pattern. You may want to use `gsub` to replace globally all  occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `{}`.

```
<%= arr.map{ |element| element.sub("a", "c") }.join(";") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic is perfect, just a minor syntax error is there. `map` accepts a block `{}` but you are passing `()`, use the following code

```
<%= arr.map { |element| element.sub("a", "c") }.join(";") %>
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as follows:

```
<%= arr.collect{|a| a.gsub("a","c")}.join(";") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **gsub** also

```
arr.map { |x| x.gsub(/[a]/, "c")}.join(";")
```